# In a large Java app, is there a way to ensure that only TLSv1.2 or above is used?

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2

If I were working on a large Java app with many developers, and in the code there are various means of connecting to https services, is there a fairly straightforward way to enforce that they are all using TLS v1.2?

I've tried using `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` and `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` in a test app, and httpclient is happy to use TLSv1 or TLSv1.1.

Alternatively, if there were a straightforward way to log the SSL connections in a manner that allows me to figure out which call the handshake is coming from, that would work and I could just pound each gopher as it comes up. Unfortunately, enabling `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` just vomits out a ton of information to STDOUT and there's no easy way for me to trace a given `*** ServerHello, TLSv1.1` to a particular server call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java8 TLSv1.2 is enabled by default but TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 are also available. **To restrict outbound connection to use TLSv1.2** configure

```
 jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
```

in `jre/lib/java.security`

This will force all connections to TLSv1.2, therefore if an existing server does not support it, the connection will fail.

With the snippet below you can check it without disabling

```
Supported Protocols: 5
 SSLv2Hello
 SSLv3
 TLSv1
 TLSv1.1
 TLSv1.2
Enabled Protocols: 3
 TLSv1
 TLSv1.1
 TLSv1.2
```

with disabledAlgorithm

```
Supported Protocols: 5
 SSLv2Hello
 SSLv3
 TLSv1
 TLSv1.1
 TLSv1.2
Enabled Protocols: 1
 TLSv1.2
```

Use this to print SSL context

```
private static void printSSLContext() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{
     SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
     context.init(null,null,null);

     SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)context.getSocketFactory();
     SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();

     String[] protocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();

     System.out.println("Supported Protocols: " + protocols.length);
     for(int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(" " + protocols[i]);
     }

     protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();

     System.out.println("Enabled Protocols: " + protocols.length);
     for(int i = 0; i < protocols.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(" " + protocols[i]);
     }

     String[] ciphers = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
     System.out.println("Enabled Ciphers: " + ciphers.length);
     for(int i = 0; i < ciphers.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(" " + ciphers[i]);
     }
    }
```

Comment: :-( Just tried it, but it still happily prints this with SSL debug on:

`$ java -Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true -Djavax.net.debug=ssl Test
...
main, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 161
main, READ: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 3801
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.1
...`

Comment: Could you include the full handshake log?

Comment: No doubt, it is tlsv1.1, i find a working example. Check it out

Comment: So I'm already on Java 8. Creating a TLSv1.2 connection is not difficult, but what I want to do is either (a) prevent any one in the application from creating a TLSv1.1 connection or (b) at least identify whenever connections are being created using TLVv1.1 or earlier.

Comment: Yes, is possible configuring in your server TLSv1.2 as the unique accepted protocol. All server have this option

Comment: Yes, it's easy enough to limit incoming traffic to TLSv1.2, but what I'm trying to do here is to limit _outbound_ connections to TLSv1.2 across the entire codebase. Most of the services being called I don't own, so I can't set them to restrict their incoming traffic to TLSv1.2.

Comment: So I just tried it with `-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv2Hello,SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSv1.1`. Unfortunately it was more than happy to create a TLSv1.1 connection with httpclient 4, and the output is exactly the same as the gist above. :-( I'm starting to think this is simply not possible and we can only comb through the code and hope to get all of them.

Comment: It not works with -D. Try it updating jre/lib/java.security. it worked for me

Comment: Ooh, yes, that works locally. That will be a good way to validate in a test or canary environment that we are not using TLS 1.1 or earlier anywhere.